# Write String to multiple txt files

Tags: java, swing

The following code writes a string to a specific file.

```
String content = "Text To be written on a File";

    File file = new File("c:/file.txt");
    FileOutputStream foutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    byte[] c = content.getBytes();

    foutput.write(c);
    foutput.flush();
    foutput.close();
```

I want to use this code in a Jbutton so every time the user clicks it, it writes the string to a NEW text file NOT OVERWRITE the existed one. I tried to do but I couldn't get the result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of different ways you can get this result, it really depends on the application. The two easiest ways to do this would to be either:

1. Append the current timestamp to the file name
2. Use the `File` API to create a "temp file" in the directory, which is guarenteed to have a unique name

Option 1:

```
String baseDir = "c:/";
File newFile = new File(baseDir, "file_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt");
// do file IO logic here...
```

Option 2:

```
String baseDir = "c:/";
File newFile = File.createTempFile("file", ".txt", new File(baseDir));
// do file IO logic here...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is great

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it to a new file, you have to **create** a new file. The name of the text file is always `file.txt` in your case.

Try this:

```
private int filecounter = 0; // this is the member of your class. Outside the function.

//inside your function
File file = new File("c:/file" + Integer.(filecounter).toString() + ".txt");
// you do something here.
filecounter++;
```

This way, your files will be stored as `file0.txt`, `file1.txt` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is great